# Converting Array of Strings with spaces to Lowercase in Javascript then Searching Through Them Fails in Webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to write a piece of code that takes an array of strings with spaces containing item names (items) and searches it for a string (str). The code works fine as long as I do not first attempt to convert the array to lowercase so that I can catch all possible cases of the search string. The code in the attached jsfiddle works fine in Firefox but not in WebKit or IE. Can anyone lend any insight?

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6zKx/16/

---

**//Array of item names, 0 contains "String"**

```
var items = new Array('Item Name Contains String', 'This item is missing it');
```

**//Function searchArray will search for String str in Array of Strings strArray**

```
function searchArray(str, strArray) {
    for (var j = 0; j < strArray.length; j++) {
        if (strArray[j].match(str)) return j;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**//Convert the items Array to lowercase so that the search is case-insensitive**

**//This works in Firefox but not in Webkit**

```
var lowerCaseItems = $.map(items, String.toLowerCase);
alert(lowerCaseItems);
```

**//This appears to create the same output but doesn't work in either Firefox or Webkit:**

```
alert(items.toString().toLowerCase());
```

**//If the array contains "battery" the function will return the positive position**

```
contains = searchArray("string", lowerCaseItems);
alert(contains);
```

**//If the id is found, show the message**

```
if ($('#noItems').length) {
    $('#emptyCart').show();
}
```

**//If str is not found show the message**

```
if (contains == -1) {
    $('#noString').show();
}
//else 
else {
    alert("String Found");
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
var lowerCaseItems = $.map(items, function(n,i){return n.toLowerCase();});
```

[jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) invokes the function on null/window context and passes the item as a parameter to the function. So, passing toLowerCase function won't work as it must be invoked on string object which jQuery.map does not do.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox is being lenient:

> The String instance methods are also available in Firefox as of JavaScript 1.6 (though not part of the ECMAScript standard) on the String object for applying String methods to any object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

That's why `String.toLowerCase` works in FF, but strictly speaking it's not part of the spec and should not be expected to work anywhere else.

Comment: @NathanielBannister if you want code: `$.map(items, function(x) { return x.toLowerCase(); });` :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the $.map() function correctly. It expects a callback function with 2 arguments. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and try this:

```
var lowerCaseItems = $.map(items, 
        function(item, index) {
            return item.toLowerCase();
        });
```

It works in Chrome.